# Why does my OS hangs for less than a second?

Tags: 18.04, freeze

I use Ubuntu 18.04 with kernel 4.15.0-39-generic.

My system:

- Intel® Core™ i7-4710HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz × 8
- 16 GB of RAM
- NVIDIA 860M
- Disk is WDC WD10S21X-24R1BT0-SSHD-8GB (03.01A01)

My system hangs for 0.3s to 0.7 second every (mean) 7 minutes. It affects audio, video, program and even CPU interrupts.

My disk S.M.A.R.T. status is OK.

Whenever this happens i get a spike in the CPU chart of System monitor.
[The freeze is always followed by the CPU3 spike and is always close to 60% of usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StxzJ.png).

There is normally no intensive use and it still happens at the same rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be your graphics driver, but more info would be nice. Make sure you're watching the exact time whenever your system hangs. Then, you can check your logs (`/var/log/syslog`) to see what the issue is. As far as I know, nVidia drivers have been a problem for a while in Linux because nVidia doesn't want to open-source their drivers like AMD. Anyway, if your log at the time it hangs says something like "nouveau" then you can be sure it's a driver issue, so you might want to switch drivers

---

**EDIT**
Reinstalling GNOME appeared to fix the issue for OP `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86533/discussion-on-answer-by-driveforms-why-does-my-os-hangs-for-less-than-a-second).